# Javascript not reading the keys and values of a dictionary in django template

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary like:

```
dest = {2: [u'canada', u'A', 'Ottawa'], 5: [u'Malaysia', u'A', 'KualaLumpur'],...}
```

Then I tried to retrieve the keys and values from `dest` in django template using javascript:

```
function categorizeReports()
{
      var a = [];
      var b = [];
      {% for i,v in dest %}
        id = '{{i}}';
        console.log('id', id)
        values = '{{v}}';
        console.log('values',values)
        {% for name, type, cat in values %}
            if(type=='A' && cat=='Ottawa')
                {
                     a.push(id,name,type,cat)
                }
            if(type=='A' && cat=='KualaLumpur')
                {
                     b.push(id,name,type,cat)
                }

        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      console.log(a)
      console.log(b)
 }
```

But both the Arrays are shown as `'an empty string'` as well as id and values are too shown as `'an empty string'`, Please help!

Comment: is it expected that Your JS code will be repeated many times?

Comment: @oleg: yes every time the template loads.

Comment: I mean if you have 10 items in dest lines ```id = '';
        console.log('id', id)
        values = '';
        console.log('values',values)``` will be present 10 times for example .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing .items

Change

```
{% for i,v in dest %}
```

to

```
{% for i,v in dest.items %}
```

Comment: Well, values will be a list type. So your syntax for pulling out name, type and cat won't work. {{ values.0 }} will get the name {{ values.1 }} will get the type...and so forth...I believe so at least. Not tested.